# PHP failing silently on apache (Mac OS monterey)

Tags: php, apache

I upgraded to Monterey and it crashed my local apache setup as php is no longer included. I have installed and codesigned php but it still doesn't work but there are no error messages.

I followed instructions here to install php:

https://wpbeaches.com/updating-to-php-versions-7-4-and-8-on-macos-12-monterey/

but this failed because the php files hadn't been appropriately signed:

"No code signing authority for module at /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so specified in LoadModule directive."

I then followed instructions here to code sign the php files:

https://www.simplified.guide/macos/apache-php-homebrew-codesign

and it now appears the php module loads successfully:

"Allowing module loading process to continue for module at /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so because module signature matches authority "Derek Winton" specified in LoadModule directive"

Despite this I can't get any php files to run and

```
phpinfo();
```

is just treated as html text.

I have added this to the bottom of httpd.conf

```
<FilesMatch .php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

and also disabled mpm_event and enabled mpm_prefork

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was inadvertently running two versions of apache. I thought I had turned off the native version of apache using

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

but because there was an error in my httpd.conf file (trying to load php) this hadn't actually worked so I had to restart my machine.

You can see what instances of apache are running with

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

The config file for the homebrew version of apache is /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf (whereas the native config file is /etc/apache2/httpd.conf). Including the php module in homebrew apache *doesn't* require code signing.